# Node Elasticsearch - Bulk indexing not working - Content-Type header [application/x-ldjson] is not supported

Tags: json, node.js, elasticsearch

Being new to elasticsearch, am exploring it by integrating with node and trying to execute the following online git example in windows.

https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/node-elasticsearch-tutorial

while trying to import the data of 1000 items from data.json, the execution 'node index.js' is failing with the following error.

By enabling the trace, I now see the following as the root cause from the bulk function.

```
"error": "Content-Type header [application/x-ldjson] is not supported",
** "status": 406**
```

I see a change log from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/changelog.html which says following

> 13.0.0 (Apr 24 2017) bulk and other APIs that send line-delimited JSON bodies now use the Content-Type: application/x-ndjson header #507

Any idea how to resolve this content type issue in index.js?

**index.js**

```
 (function () {
  'use strict';

  const fs = require('fs');
  const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
  const esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'error'
  });

  const bulkIndex = function bulkIndex(index, type, data) {
    let bulkBody = [];

    data.forEach(item => {
      bulkBody.push({
        index: {
          _index: index,
          _type: type,
          _id: item.id
        }
      });      
      bulkBody.push(item);
    });

   esClient.bulk({body: bulkBody})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(`Inside bulk3...`);
      let errorCount = 0;
      response.items.forEach(item => {
        if (item.index && item.index.error) {
          console.log(++errorCount, item.index.error);
        }
      });
      console.log(`Successfully indexed ${data.length - errorCount} out of ${data.length} items`);
    })
    .catch(console.err);
  };

  // only for testing purposes
  // all calls should be initiated through the module
  const test = function test() {
    const articlesRaw = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
    const articles = JSON.parse(articlesRaw);
    console.log(`${articles.length} items parsed from data file`);
    bulkIndex('library', 'article', articles);
  };

  test();

  module.exports = {
    bulkIndex
  };
} ());
```

*my local windows environment:*

java version **1.8.0_121**
elasticsearch version **6.1.1**
node version **v8.9.4**
npm version **5.6.0**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`bulk`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-bulk) function doesn't return a promise. It accepts a callback function as a parameter.

```
esClient.bulk(
  {body: bulkBody},
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) { console.err(err); return; }
    console.log(`Inside bulk3...`);
    let errorCount = 0;
    response.items.forEach(item => {
      if (item.index && item.index.error) {
        console.log(++errorCount, item.index.error);
      }
    });
    console.log(`Successfully indexed ${data.length - errorCount} out of ${data.length} items`);
  }
)
```

or use [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert a function accepting an `(err, value) => ...` style callback to a function that returns a promise.

```
const esClientBulk = util.promisify(esClient.bulk)
esClientBulk({body: bulkBody})
  .then(...)
  .catch(...)
```

**EDIT:** Just found out that elasticsearch-js [supports both](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-conventions.html#api-conventions-cb) callbacks and promises. So this should not be an issue.

By looking at the `package.json` of the project that you've linked, it uses `elasticsearch-js` version `^11.0.1` which is an old version and that is sending requests with `application/x-ldjson` header for bulk upload, which is [not supported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/23049) by newer elasticsearch versions. So, upgrading `elasticsearch-js` to a newer version (current latest is `14.0.0`) should fix it.

Comment: Thanks @bless for your inputs. I have edited my post as my further trouble shooting found a different error now - unsupported Content-Type header 'application/x-ldjson'. Please go through my post and let me know if you have any directions. Thanks.

Comment: @VeeAar Can you also mention the version of the `elasticsearch-js` npm package you're using. On a first look, it looks like you're using an older version of `elasticsearch-js` which is sending requests with `application/x-ldjson` header, which is [not supported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/23049) by newer elasticsearch versions.

Comment: @VeeAar Just had a look at the `package.json` of the project that you've linked. And it looks like a version issue. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @bless. Your inputs on upgrading to the latest version of elasticsearch.js worked. I am now able to index successfully using the buld function.